# High TTFB time on AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services

I've setup a Auto scaling group with 2 ec2 m1.medium instances behind ELB with sticky session and RDS mySQL - Multi-AZ t2.medium (LAMP Stack).

All my static files are on cloudfront dist. Only API requests are being served from the web server.

I'm experiencing high TTFB (over 1.20 sec), can you please advise?